# Survey data - sum of column based on criteria of multiple columns and rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an extremely complex (well it is to me) question that I am hoping someone can assist me with. I'll go through the scenario. 
I am trying to gather data by surveying some people.  Each question links to a particular category (where I've allocated it either `a +1` or `a -1` score to determine characteristics depending on whether the person agrees or disagrees with the statement).

e.g referring to the Sample Table below if they select "agree" to Question 1 they will get `a +1` score for `CAT7 (Category 7)`.  If they Agree with Question 5, they get `a -1` for `CAT4` and `a +1` for `CAT8`.

I have tried `SUMPRODUCTS, INDEX, MATCH, VLOOKUPS, COUNTIFS` - I could be missing something. Might have to go some VBA code? If anyone can help.

I basically want scores for each category

Please help! It's much appreciated!

[image: Sample Table]

Comment: The image link doesn't work (I'm using Google Chrome). Since the image doesn't work I can't really help you. So I will give you an answer that can guide you along the way. It sounds like the survey could be done with formulas only. Your survey-questions seems to be True or False which makes it a whole lot easier. You seem to be interested in VBA, so my suggestion would be to take a look at creating forms. A better solution would be to work in Access, if you have access to it (No pun intended). Here is a [Link](http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html) on how you create forms in Excel.

Comment: Can you please show us what the question and it's answer look like in your sheet so we can understand where to check ?

Comment: Sorry - the image link is working for me.  How strange.  I'll try to explain it. Thank you for trying to help. 

In Column A I have the questions, Column B - F are the categories.  Against each question (in the same row), there are -1 or +1 against a few of the categories (e.g. Question 1 might have a +1 in Column B and a -1 in Column D).  I want to find a way so that when I get their survey results that are agree/disagree, when they have selected "Agree", return (and sum) the column value for each category (column).  Does that make sense? @EliasWick

Comment: @Robs237 The link works now! See my answer and write back if you are looking for another solution.

Comment: You would need to specify a lookup table i.e. which categories go with which question.

Comment: What is your expected result.

Comment: Ideally I would like a table with every persons name down column A, the categories along Row 1, with their individual score per category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This will utilize matrix function `MMULT` with `OFFSET` and `MATCH` and here is the **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) for you to try:

```
=MMULT(OFFSET($K$2,MATCH($A16,$K$3:$K$7,0),1,,COUNTA($L$2:$U$2)),IF(B$3:B$12<>"",OFFSET($A$2,1,MATCH(B$15,$B$2:$I$2,0),COUNTA($A$3:$A$12)),0))
```

What this does is use matrix function `MMULT`to multiple table 1 and table 2.  The `OFFSET` is to find the correct column and row to do the math.  Just think this is the simplified array formula to find `person V` with the corresponding `CAT1`.

```
=MMULT($L3:$U3,IF(B$3:B$12<>"",B$3:B$12,0))
```

Hope this helps.  Please remember you will need to adjust your range to fit your setup.

Comment: It works! This is perfect!!! Thank you so much! You have no idea how appreciative I am! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an example of your desired data ?

Table 'F8Uo4' with the statements : {table1}

```
Statement /.../ CAT4 / CAT5 /.../ CAT8
...
Q3        /.../      /   1  /.../  
Q4
Q5        /.../  -1  /      /.../   1
Q6
Q7        /.../      /      /.../   1
```

Answers to the survey given by the people : {table2}

```
Name / Q3 / Q5 / ... / Q7

Jake / A  / D  / ... / D
Jeff / A  / D  / ... / A
Joe  / A  / A  / ... / A
John / D  / A  / ... / A
```

Table with the desired results ? {table3} (reading your comment, I think I should delete this one)

```
Result /.../ CAT4 / CAT5 /.../ CAT8

Q3                    3  
Q4
Q5            -2                 2
Q6
Q7                               3

Total  /.../  -2  /  +3  /.../  +5
```

Is this more like it ? {table4} by reading {table1} and {table2}

```
Name /.../ CAT4 / CAT5 /.../ CAT8

Jake /.../   0  /   1  /.../   0 ' approves Q3, so CAT5+1
Jeff /.../   0  /   1  /.../   1 ' approves Q3+Q7, so CAT5+1 and CAT8+1
Joe  /.../  -1  /   1  /.../   2 ' approves Q3+Q5+Q7, so CAT5+1, CAT4-1, CAT8+1+1
John /.../  -1  /   0  /.../   2 ' approves Q5+Q7, so CAT4-1 and CAT8+1+1
```

Comment: Ideally I would like a table with every persons name down column A, the categories along Row 1, with their individual score per category.

Comment: yes, that last table is what we are looking for.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated